# В одной переменной передавать значение без кавычки и с кавычкой

Tags: php, laravel

Значение переменной должно будет выглядеть таким образом

```
 $firstName = ТОО "134";
```

То есть на стороне клиента, оно должно иметь такой вид, текст без кавычки,  а второе значение с кавычкой, и должно это передаваться в одну переменную,  как это можно сделать?

$firstName = $data['firstName'] ?? null;

Я по ключу передаю туда значение таким образом

```
 "firstName" : "ТОО 134"
```

Но в конечном итоге для клиента должно быть так

```
наименование: ТОО "134";
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Что за задачу пытаешься решить? Это в целом некомпилируемый код будет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский на работе дали,  я через постмен отправляю запрос,  и передаю соответсвенно  так  "firstName" : "ТОО 134", но у клиента это должно быть так  ТОО "134", разве на своей стороне я не могу как-то конвертировать или через preg_match как-то сделать, пока не понимаю, как можно сделать

Comment: В базе хранится "ТОО 134" а вы хотите получить 'ТОО "134"' во вью верно?

Comment: Да можете через регуляки конечно, какой формат имен будет использоваться? всегда ТОО но разные цифры?

Comment: @YauhenKib нет,  я наооборот добавляю, а не извлекаю,  я передаю это так "firstName" : "ТОО 134", а у клиента оно должно быть так ТОО "134", то есть на своей стороне я как-то должен конвертировать,  чтобы   второй текст был уже в кавычках

Comment: `$value = "escaped \"value\"";` либо `$value = 'qwe "asd"'`

Comment: @YauhenKib  нет не всегда ТОО, и цифры всегда разные будут

Comment: приведите еще несколько примеров имен, чтобы помочь вам составить регулярное выражение

Comment: @teran $firstName = $data['firstName'] ?? null; я так передаю по ключу, с твоим кодом не пойму как сделать

Comment: То есть получается всё, что надо, это цифру писать в кавычках?

Comment: если у вас есть строка, котора начинаяется с чего-то, потом пробел, а потом еще что-то, и это последнее что-то надо завернуть в кавычки, то 1) `[$first, $second] = explode(' ', $str, 2); $result = "{$first} \"{$second}\""` либо 2) `preg_replace("/^(.*?)\s(.*)/", '\$1 "\$2"', $str)`

Comment: если второе это всегда число, и именно число в строке надо обернуть в кавычки, то это опять другой паттерн. Сформулируйте нормально с разными вариантами

Comment: @teran там вообще оказывается может и не понадобиться регулярка, там вообще будет всегда по разному приходить текст, кавычки могут быть и не быть, и они могут быть где угодно и сколько, вопрос тогда такой, в json такой формат можно передавать ТОО "134" такой для примера допустим, он может быть и таким: БЛА бла "бла" бла 123

Comment: передавайте в json что угодно, если вы его кодируете через json_encode а не какое-то рукоблудство делаете, то никакого дополнительного кода, связанного с кавычками, не требуется

Comment: @LaraCast `может быть и таким: БЛА бла "бла" бла 123` --- вы делаете какойто бред %)) Мне кажется сами не понимаете что и зачем

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Задачу просто не правильно понял, когда ТимЛид объяснял)